# When can we restrict/condition a probability measure to a subset of zero measure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $\mu(C)>0$, $$\mu_C(A)=\frac{\mu(A\cap C)}{\mu(C)}$$ is well-defined. If $\mu(C)=0$ things get hairy. If $C=\{x\}$ (single point) then $\mu_C=\delta_x$. If $C=\bigcup_{i=1}^nx_i$ (a finite collection of points) and $\mu$ has density $f$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure then $$\mu_C\propto \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\delta_{x_i}$$ (as long as not all $f(x_i)$ are zero).

What about general case of $\mu(C)=0$? Any conditions on $\mu$ that would allow such a restriction? Would non-singularity be sufficient? Is the following limit well-defined:

$$\mu_C(A)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\mu_{C_\epsilon}(A)$$
where $C_\epsilon=\bigcup_{x\in C}B_x(\epsilon)$?

Comment: If $C=\{T=x\}$ for some random variable $T$ the measure $\mu(A|T=x)$ can be defined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability

Comment: You can always write $C=\{1_C=1\}$ but it's not helpful for $A\subseteq C$ if $\mu(C)=0$ as $\mu(\cdot|1_C=1)$ can be defined arbitrarily.